# Azure Automation runbook PowerShell how to check when Set-AzStorageAccount has finished

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

When setting the redundancy from LRS to GRS with the following line `Set-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName -SkuName $myRundandancy` the PowerShell code continues and does not wait for the Azure storage account to finish being set to GRS.

Is there a way to monitor this and only continue code execution once this process has finished?

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate more and clear?

Comment: When I run this comment, it was successfully executed to the point where `Set-AzStorageAccount` finished and displayed an output like [this](https://i.imgur.com/naelJzx.png)  Once refresh my storage account it changed into GRS like [this](https://i.imgur.com/o4roSSR.png)

Comment: @Imran for me the runbook completes immediately, however, when I go to the storage account, it will show a message that it's still in process and it will stay like that for a while at least 10+ minutes even though there's no data. I updated my post with a screenshot

Comment: @Imran I am trying to set the account type from LRS to GRS with the following command `Set-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName -SkuName $myRundandancy`, when I do that, script continues immediately, it does not wait for the command/process to finish. I need to script to wait for the whole command/process to finish

Comment: I have tried the same scenario in both runbook and PowerShell it shows me the same message and command executed and changed to GRS like  [this](https://i.imgur.com/znsJ0G6.png) but that message failover cannot yet to be initidated.....After reflecting in portal still running in code check [this](https://i.imgur.com/SUTeRUJ.png) AFAIK it's not possible to wait for the whole command/process to finish. Unfortunately, there no direct cmd in Azure provides real-time progress updates on the data synchronization process.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in Azure Automation runbook I got the same error message and code executed changed to GRS successfully like below:

[image]

[image]

> Is there a way to monitor this and only continue code execution once this process has finished?

The error message failover cannot yet to be initiated If you're specifically waiting for the completion of data synchronization after changing the replication type of an Azure Storage Account, until the failover is available. Unfortunately, there no direct Azure PowerShell cmdlet that provides real-time progress updates on the data synchronization process.

You can check Last Sync Time property in PowerShell like below:

```c
$lastSyncTime = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "<RGName>" -Name "<storage-account>" -IncludeGeoReplicationStats).GeoReplicationStats.LastSyncTime
Write-Output "Last Sync Time: $lastSyncTime"
```

***Output***:

[image]

***Reference***:
[Check the Last Sync Time property for a storage account - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/last-sync-time-get?tabs=azure-powershell)